# UIActionController appears behind UIToolbar

Tags: ios, iphone

Converting to UIActionController with style UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet in my iPhone app, I find that it appears BEHIND the UITaskbar I have at the bottom of every window, hiding the "Cancel" menu entry.  UIActionSheet works correctly.  This happens in the simulator and on the phone.

The taskbar is "owned" by the main window and appears in all pushed views.  I was having similar problems with other windows until I changed the UIToolbar to opaque (translucent = NO).

iOS version 8.1.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what is `UITaskBar` in your context?

Comment: Sorry: should be UIToolbar.